# What is the process for evaluating questions migrated from Biblical Hermeneutics?

Tags: discussion

I had this question recently migrated from BH.SE.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/80359/according-to-those-who-believe-philippians-26-says-jesus-is-god-why-did-paul-a

I was open to it being migrated to C SE, because maybe it is a better fit.

The question was immediately denied a migration request and sent back, so now it's closed, apparently.

I was given no opportunity to fine-tune the question for C.SE. Just the comment

> "You're gonna have to try harder than that to frame a question for
> this site. Could you please just ask a particular denomination?"

from mod Peter Turner. Hey mod, how can I reformulate the question for C.SE if you've sent it back to BH.SE where it is now closed? Since it was migrated, it obviously wasn't framed originally as a question for this site.

So are questions migrated to C.SE evaluated differently by mods than new questions posted on C.SE? Usually, you are given a notice so you can fine-tune it. In this case, nothing apparently.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always apparent to a moderator handling answer flags that a question was migrated and the impact of closing a migrated question is much more severe (by design) than the impact of closing a question asked on a particular site.

So, I'm sorry that happened, that comment was not appropriate for BH.SE for sure.

Here "Those who believe X interpretation of a particular scripture passage" is too vague.  There's no authority by which to evaluate the credentials of a person who believes a particular interpretation.

For instance, when it comes to the Hypostatic Union, there are some old heresies wherein it was believed that Jesus became God at some point and others that say He was God only in spirit and others that say he was God sometimes and not other times and others that say He had godlike attributes which He wore like a mask so you can't evaluate an answer from that perspective alongside a mainstream or scholastic answer coming from Orthodox, Catholic or Reformation traditions.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Why is it not always apparent? Shouldn't the mods check? I know that usually you have to scope on C SE, and would of course have modified the question if given the chance -  I didn't know if it would, in fact, be migrated from BH.

Comment: @one I'll be sure to check now, I was handling flags on the comments (these questions do rile people up, which I am entirely not a fan of) and the facts were probably there, but I wasn't looking for it, I mean, I wasn't hunting down your question to close it,  I think it could have easily been turned into the question you re-asked (which I'm not a fan of, but I can live with).   Either way, I couldn't do much more than close the question  to end the discourse in the comments and I don't get a choice about the automated parts.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators usually don't consult each other on an individual moderation action because we're usually on the same page, or at least close enough that it doesn't matter. So in this case I thought the question would be better on this site and migrated it here. Peter then saw it and thought it wasn't quite good enough, so closed it.

What then happened is a quirk of the migration system: when a question that has been migrated gets closed, it also gets locked, meaning that it can't be edited and reopened. Unfortunately there's no way to tell the system that a migrated question should be closed but left unlocked because it could be improved and reopened, rather than locked because it never should have been migrated and has no chance of improvement.

Now there is one thing that the mods can do, which is to unlink a migrated question. This essentially turns it into duplicate questions on both sites, rather than a migrated question that only leaves a trace behind on the original site. This would allow the two questions to then diverge, as well as allowing them to be closed and edited like normal. It's a very rarely used option (I'm not sure I've ever actually done it in the years since I've been elected a mod), but it could have helped in this case. But as you just went and asked it again there's now no point in using that option.

Your question being locked and returned was an unfortunate situation, but I hope you understand that it wasn't done intentionally.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and I understand how the end result wasn't intentional - Peter's snarky comment was intentional, though!